How to deserialize a JSON encoded DateTime with a specified Timezone in Rust with serde?
Here is a JSON encoded object with a datetime and timezone. I believe this is an ISO 8601 format with 6 digits of precision for fractions of a second. (Microsecond precision.)
{
    "time": "2024-08-06T11:49:09.529856Z"
}

This is how I currently deserialize this structure in Rust code:
use std::str::FromStr;
use serde::Serialize;
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
struct MyStruct {
    time: chrono::DateTime<chrono::offset::Utc>,
}

let serialized = r'{"time":"2024-08-06T11:49:09.529856Z"}';

let deserialized =
    serde_json::from_str::<MyStruct>(&serialized)
    .expect("failed to deserialize");

It seems strange to have to specify the datetime timezone offset as part of the chrono::DateTime type, considering that this information is part of the encoded string data, and not part of the DateTime type.
What am I doing wrong here?

I don't think you're doing anything wrong per se. But you are declaring a type with your struct, and the compiler can't know at compile time what sort of date string your JSON has at runtime, that's why you have to tell it what you're expecting. For example if you use the parse_from_rfc3339) to parse your date string you will get back that type and not have to superfluously provide it, but that's a runtime operation and that method returns a Result type in case the parse fails.

The DateTime will be converted to UTC, keeping the same time but changing the timezone.
If you want to keep the timezone, use FixedOffset instead:
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
struct MyStruct {
    time: chrono::DateTime<chrono::offset::FixedOffset>,
}


There is no standard JSON date time format. A commonly used one is the one you showed. The number of decimals for the seconds is usually some fixed number (in your case six digits = microseconds). The last letter Z is the time zone. Z stands for UTC but any letter is allowed and should be handled.
You might also get time since some starting date in milliseconds or nanoseconds, if the date is created by windows. So best is to have one method that tries different formats until you find one that matches, unless the format is clearly documented.
(As far as JSON is concerned you have a string, but windows time might be a large integer).

Aside, but one of my favorite (and by that I mean least favorite) "JSON is not Javascript" bugs to track down are integers in JSON that are bigger than JS's Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER value.

I'm not sure my question was clear. What would happen if the JSON encoded datetime did not have a timezone of UTC? For example, what if it were ETC, +05:00, etc? This is why I'm thinking there may be a problem with what I have written.
